# Why won't sbt-assembly shade json4s using inLibrary?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

Using sbt-assembly 0.14.6:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" %% "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

Creating an uber jar for a Spark app with sbt-assembly, including a couple dependencies to be shaded:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" % "json4s-native_2.11" % "3.5.3",
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3",
```

That's actually a second attempt, I really want to

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.3",
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3",
```

but thought maybe shading was causing my trouble when using `%%` in the moduleID. So, what works and what doesn't:

sbt-assembly can shade a couple libraries like so:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.json4s.**" -> "shaded_json4s.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.typesafe.config.**" -> "my_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3")
    .inProject
),
```

Example shaded classes:

```
my_conf/parser/ConfigNode.class
shaded_json4s/FieldSerializer.class
```

Both libraries get shaded. I'd like to get more specific, avoiding inAll:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.json4s.**" -> "shaded_json4s.@1")
    .inLibrary("org.json4s" % "json4s-native_2.11" % "3.5.3")
    .inProject,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.typesafe.config.**" -> "my_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3")
    .inProject
),
```

But that doesn't shade json4s classes:

```
my_conf/parser/ConfigNode.class
org/json4s/FieldSerializer.class
```

But what I started with, and would really prefer is:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.json4s.**" -> "shaded_json4s.@1")
    .inLibrary("org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.3")
    .inProject,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.typesafe.config.**" -> "my_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3")
    .inProject
),
```

But that doesn't shade json4s classes, either:

```
my_conf/parser/ConfigNode.class
org/json4s/FieldSerializer.class
```

Is there something I need to do differently for shading to work on json4s when using inLibrary?

Comment: have you found the answer yet?

Comment: @MinhThai - Sorry, no. We're still using inAll, and that seems to be working well enough.

Comment: actually I have fixed this similar issue (but with another library, Shapeless). The root cause for me is the locale setting of my linux machine...

Comment: @MinhThai. Wow, good catch! I would not have thought to consider that.

Comment: @MinThai Can you be more specific what steps you took?

Comment: @MinhThai, I am trying to Shade Shapeless using sbt assembly as well. Would you mind share with me how did you do that?